# How to have dynamic multitype value in Dart/Flutter when using @JsonSerializable()?

Tags: flutter, dart, jsonserializer, json-annotation

I am using Flutter with `json_annotation` library and have one data class that is used to represent json response coming from one api.

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:app/dtos/user.dart';
import 'package:app/dtos/limited_user.dart';


part 'pending_project.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class PendingProject {
  @JsonKey(name: "user")
  final User|LimitedUser user; // here I might have sometimes returned User type other types LimitedUser

  @JsonKey(name: "updatedAt")
  final String updatedAt;

  PendingProject(this.user, this.updatedAt);

  factory PendingProject.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$PendingProjectFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$PendingProjectToJson(this);
}
```

The api returns different values for `user` field based on some logic.
Sometimes objects of type `User` other types of type `LimitedUser`

I have both those objects defined but cannot make it work in the json schema above.

How can I leave user object as dynamic maybe or json string and further parse manually in code or some other solution

Both `User` and `LimitedUser` have one common field named `type` that allows us to differentiate what we got back.

for User, type="user"

for LimitedUser, type="limitedUser"

all the other fields can be different we cannot assume anything else

PS:
pending_project.g.dart is auto generated file with the library itself by running `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`

Comment: How do you know which class it is when you get the json? Do those two have a relationship (does one extend the other) or are they completely separate entities?

Comment: Let us assume those are completely separate entities. Can I leave the `user` field as json string and parse manually in code (the code knows what to expects based on user roles). Also I can tell by checking if a specific field "type" exists inside the object. `if type==="user" or type ==="limitedUser"` that is why I am wondering if can have some dynamic mapper of sort and "union type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by using `fromJson` as below

```
@JsonKey(name: "user", fromJson: mapUser)
final Object user;


/// other code

Object mapUser(Map<String, dynamic> value)  {
  if (value['type'] == 'user') {
    User.fromJson(value);
  }

  return LimitedUser.fromJson(value);
}
```

The other code in ui is checking:

```
if (obj is User) {
  return somewidgetforuser(obj);
}
return somewidgedforlimiteduser(obj);
```